# How to check if string is in a dictionary dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**1. Summarize the problem**

I have a text file and a  specific dictionary containing words in a dataframe.
The txt file contains sentences (Strings) separated with lines.

Only a specific column of the dictionary is relevant for me and contains the keywords that I want to match with my text.
I want then to print the best match(by best I mean the longest one) in a dataframe.

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**

I created two Dataframes: one for the output and the other to import the csv dictionary:

```
Output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['stuff','Bestmatch'])
MyDictionary = pd.read_csv('mydic.csv', sep=r'\t', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
```

**3. Show some code**
Then I tried to code the main function:

```
def fetchword():
    with open (mytext.txt", "w+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for value in MyDictionary["substance_name"].values:
```

Here, I am not sure what I can do to finish the loop.

```
f.close()
```

PS: if there are many matches in the `MyDictionary` column, I want to choose the longest one and to print it into a new dataframe

Example for the csv dictionary file MyDictionary:

```
substance_name  Quantity
Acetaminophen   3
ibuprofen   4
Levothyroxin    5
Metformin   7
```

My text file for instance:

```
Acetaminophen 3x/d for one week
ibuprofen 1/d for 3 days
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the CSV file?

Comment: I edited my post with a CSV example

Comment: I have added an answer. I need one more clarification: what do you really mean by longest one? size of the name or number of matches.

Comment: The longest one. For instance "Acetaminophen category A section B" is a better match than "Acetaminophen category A". Apologies, I may have forgotten to tell you that the "substance_name" string can be composed with multiple words

Comment: Okay. I have updated my answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: I have the errors:
in <module>
    out=fetchword(MyDictionary)

in fetchword
    data.append([value,lines.count(value), len(value)])
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: I am trying to understand the error message: I should not have this error since 'data' has been defined as a list, isn't it? This is strange.

Comment: There is some error in `lines = str(f.readlines())`

Comment: The file had flaws. The code however works well. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works. The tradition is stackoverflow to upvote and accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer and upvoted. It is just not displayed because I don't have enough reputation points but normally you should still have received the +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
  
MyDictionary = pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter='\t', encoding='utf-8')
def fetchword(df):
        data=[]
        with open ("test.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = str(f.readlines())
            print(df.columns)
            for value in df["substance_name"].values:
               data.append([value,lines.count(value), len(value)])
        f.close()
        data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Word','Count','Length'])
        return(data)

out = fetchword(MyDictionary)
```

**Output:**

```
            Word  Count  Length
0  Acetaminophen      1      13
1      ibuprofen      1       9
2   Levothyroxin      0      12
3      Metformin      0       9
```

Then, you can filter the `out` as you like:

```
print(out.loc[[out[out['Count']>0]['Length'].argmax()]])
```

**Output**:

```
            Word  Count  Length
0  Acetaminophen      1      13
```